# How to compute "outer subtraction" for datetime in Matlab

Tags: matlab, datetime, matrix

In Matlab I cam compute

```
>> [1 2 3] - [1;2]
ans =
     0     1     2
    -1     0     1
K>> [1;2] - [1 2 3]
ans =
     0    -1    -2
     1     0    -1
```

Unfortunately, if I do the same with `datetime`, I fail:

```
>> NaT(1, 3) - NaT(2, 1)
Data inputs must be the same size, or any of them can be a scalar.
```

Why and is it possible to overcome?

Comment: if `.-` also fails, then presumably the datetime object does not support broadcasting yet. Try using `bsxfun` or `repmat` accordingly.

Comment: @Tasos `.-` is an Octave-only thing.  `bsxfun` also doesn't work for datetime arrays.